# Can't play HD videos on PC

Tags: windows, video

My system has an AMD Athlon(tm) Processor LE 1600 2.21 GHz, and 896 MB RAM.

I can't play HD 720p & 1080p videos on that PC. I'm using MPC and VLC player. When I open the videos, it shows a black screen, and the computer lags/freezes.

How could I solve this problem, or is my hardware not supporting the playback of these resolutions?

Comment: What happens when you attempt to play these videos?  Your hardware is over 6 years old.  You should expect some performance problems.

Comment: I don't think player is a problem, as Ramhound said hardware may be the issue. And what do you mean by *can't play* ?

Comment: Increasing the cache size (somewhere in the player's settings) could help, but well the hardware part clearly isn't the best for playing HD files.

Comment: Given system should play HD files, but not as high framerate as intended. And "can't play" =/= "low framerate or choppy playback".

Comment: You should head to http://superuser.com/contact and have your two accounts merged (the one used for editing and the one which you posted your question with)

Answer (score 0):

HD 1080p is demanding to play even on a good hardware, because it demands same data speed transmission from hard drive. Try to choose smaller resolutions! VLC is very robust, it shall not be the problem